# Como ignorar y convertir a un numero fijo?

Tags: java

Aquí es un método despues de crear el metodo constructor y get, aquí quiero saber como convierto el getPrecioBase en x ignorando el valor que puse en la instancia del objeto.

```
 public double precioNeto(){
   //Aquí quiero cambiar por ejemplo si es pino su precio base 40
   if (getTipoMadera().equalsIgnoreCase("Pino")){
       double x=40, total;
       total= (getPrecioBase());
       return total;
       //en otro caso también quiero cambiar por ejemplo si es caoba su precio base es 80
   }else if(getTipoMadera().equalsIgnoreCase("Caoba")){
       double x=80, total;
       total= (getPrecioBase());       
       return total;
   }
    return 0;

}
```

Por ejemplo he creado la instancia del objeto en otra clase

```
 mueble[0]=new Muebles("pino", "Celeste", 0);//el 0 es el precioBase
```

Así ignorando el valor "0" que puse, para que me imprima el valor de la variable x por tipoMadera por consola

---

Lo que pienso poner es así:

```
total= (getPrecioBase()=x);
```

o

```
getPrecioBase()=x);  
x=getPrecioBase());//también intente me funciono pero el resultado es 0
```

Ninguno de ellos me sale correcto.
 Espero que me ayuden

Comment: Debes crear un método `setPrecioBase(x)` donde el parámetro sea el nuevo valor e iguales éste valor a una variable `precioBase`

Comment: Lo más simple quizá sea manejar un array o un map donde guardes en pares los precios base de acuerdo al material, luego puedes tener un método `setPrecioBase` el cual, dependiendo del material pasado, establezca el precio base del objeto. Si te interesa esa idea de puedo mostrar un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

no tenes los setters?

Los getters se usan para traer un valor y los setters para modificarlo o setearlo.

Yo haria algo asi

```
public void precioNeto(Muebles mueble){
   //Aquí quiero cambiar por ejemplo si es pino su precio base 40
   if (mueble.getTipoMadera().equalsIgnoreCase("Pino")){
       mueble.setPrecioBase(40);
       //en otro caso también quiero cambiar por ejemplo si es caoba su precio base es 80
   }else if(mueble.getTipoMadera().equalsIgnoreCase("Caoba")){
      mueble.setPrecioBase(80);      
   }

}
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar un set, te pongo un ejemplo:

Intente crear una clase que imagino estas usando:

```
class Muebles {
    private String madera;
    private String color;
    private double precioBase;

    public void Muebles(String madera, String color, double precioBase) {
        this.madera = madera;
        this.color = color;
        this.precioBase = precioBase;
    }
    public double getPrecioBase() {
        return this.precioBase;
    }
    public void setPrecioBase(double precioBase) {
        this.precioBase = precioBase;
    }
}
```

Ahora bien solo cree el `get` y el set para el `precioBase` en el ejemplo pero deberías hacer un `set` y `get` para tus todos tus atributos.
Ahora lo podrías utilizar de la siguiente forma:

```
Muebles mueble = new Muebles("pino", "Celeste", 0);
mueble.setPrecioBase(15);
```

Espero te sirva ;) Saludos.